# Is there any way I can have excel automatically convert to the default theme before saving?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

Please see the attached image. I have essentially created a Dark Mode template for myself. All I did was change the cell formatting (changed background,border,text colors) and moved this template to the XLSTART folder, which ensures that every new worksheet I open is consistent with this formatting.

The question I have, is that is it possible for me to work with this theme, but save the sheet in the default format? As much as I love working on this template, I can almost guarantee that some external parties that I send spreadsheets to will not appreciate this.

Essentially what I'm looking for is:

1. Work with the custom "Dark" cell style that I have created.
2. Save with the "Normal" (default) cell style in excel (essentially a macro that does "CTRL-A", and then clicks "Normal" cell style everytime I save a document.

Does anyone know if this is possible? I'm sure I can write a script in Python that does this, but it's faster to just press CRTL-A and click "Normal" instead of launching my IDE and running the script.

Thanks in advance!

[Dark Mode Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFLlS.png)

Comment: Have you looked at `Cells.ClearFormats`?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.clearformats

Comment: Yes, I have heard of Cells.ClearFormats, but not sure how I would implement this so that I don't have to manually run that command everytime.

Comment: You could do this as a `beforesave` event to execute that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of "ThisWorkbook", you can put a `BeforeSave` event, e.g.:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cells.ClearFormats
End Sub
```

You can spruce this up to affect multiple sheets, etc.

---

**Edit1:**

Adding comment as code.  The below would remove the fill from the interior and change the font color back to the default black.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cells.Interior.Color = xlNone
    Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Now I assume this just clears all formatting. Not sure if this would work perfectly because I also wanted bolded/underlined/borders that I have editted to be shown, just with the normal colors.

Comment: @Maestro So you want to use just `Cells.Interior.Color = xlNone` and `Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 0`?  You would put those inside of the `BeforeSave` event.

Comment: @Maestro edited post to show the previous comment.